# variable substitution in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can anyone please help, I am preparing the condition statement at the backend, that needs to be substituted in the pandas-dataframe but it is failing.

```
st="(df['ColA']>48) & (df['ColB']<14)" 
df[st]
```

> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>
> if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

I just verified manually that the below is working.

```
df[(df['ColA']>48) & (df['ColB']<14)]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes. Use:

```
st = (df['ColA']>48) & (df['ColB']<14)
df[st]
```